# How to get values from a defaultdict using a new combination of keys?

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have the following defaultdict:

```
dictA = {"a": {"b": 0.1, "c": 0.2}, "b": {"c": 0.3}}
```

From this dict, I need to append the values to a list using the following combination of keys:

```
order = [("b","b"), ("b","a"), ("b","c"), ("a","b", ("a","a"), ("a","c"), ("c","b"), ("c","a"), ("c","c")]
```

If the keys combination are the same (for example ("a", "a")), the value should be zero. So the final result should look something like the following:

```
result = [0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0]
```

I have tried the following

```
 dist = []
 for index1, member1 in enumerate(order):
    curr = dictA.get(member1, {})
    for index2, member2 in enumerate(order): 
        val = curr.get(member2)
        if member1 == member2:
            val = 0
        if member2 not in curr:
            val = None
        dist.append(val)
```

But obviously this is not working as intended. Can someone help me with this? Thank you

Comment: Is `dictA` arbitrarily deep or does it just have 1 level?

Comment: It only has one level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def get(d, first, second):
    return d.get(second, {}).get(first, 0.0)

dictA = {"a": {"b": 0.1, "c": 0.2}, "b": {"c": 0.3}}
order = [("b", "b"), ("b", "a"), ("b", "c"), ("a", "b"), ("a", "a"), ("a", "c"), ("c", "b"), ("c", "a"), ("c", "c")]

result = [get(dictA, first, second) or get(dictA, second, first) for first, second in order]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.0]
```

Or the less *pythonic* alternative:

```
def get(d, first, second):
    return d.get(second, {}).get(first, 0.0)


dictA = {"a": {"b": 0.1, "c": 0.2}, "b": {"c": 0.3}}
order = [("b", "b"), ("b", "a"), ("b", "c"), ("a", "b"), ("a", "a"), ("a", "c"), ("c", "b"), ("c", "a"), ("c", "c")]

result = []
for first, second in order:
    value = get(dictA, first, second)
    if value:
        result.append(value)
    else:
        value = get(dictA, second, first)
        result.append(value)


print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.0]
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I probably tried the less pythonic approach. But I see my mistake now.

Comment: note that this solution will work as requested (put 0.0 where duplicate keys) only when the "dictA" has no duplicated nested keys (something like: dictA = {"a": {"a": 0.5"}}